# How can I list child entries from parent in EE Structure?

Tags: structure, nested-list, child

I'm working with EE v2.9.3 and Structure v3.3.14.5
I have simple structure hierarchy

```
MAIN PARENT
- parent 1
---child 1a
---child 1b
- parent 2
---child 2a
```

and so on. I want to create json for my javascript file. So, I started with creating snippet with that structure:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d = [
      {exp:structure:entries channel="first-channel" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination" dynamic="no" status="open"}
    {          
        "name": "{title}",
        "locations": [
         {
            "name": "{title}",
            "phone": "xxx",
            "email": "xxx",                
          }
        ],  
    },            
      {/exp:structure:entries}

];
console.log(d);
</script>
```

And it's working. I can see my objects created with names parent 1, parent 2 etc. Now I want to create "locations" key (whatever there's 1 or more entries) which will be contains my child entries like child 1a, 1b etc. I tried with nested `{exp:structure:entires}` but it doesn't work. So my question is - how can I create `locations` key based on nested `exp` loop?

Answer (score 0):

How did you nest the second entries tag? If you just added it within it might not work, might need to use an embed. But someone else might know if a better way.

Comment: I just drag&drop positions in structure tree but entries have proper parent_id values.

Comment: No i mean how did you nest in the template?

Comment: Nevermind, I manage to do it with `embed`. Thanks for the tip :)